# How can I make my VGG model more accurate from the start?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I'm trying to do a image classification task and for that I'm using the VGG model. Right now, I'm using 3 epochs as I don't want the training to take a lot of time, but from the start my model is giving really bad accuracy. Can anyone tell me how can I make this model more accurate ? This is why I've when I'm creating the model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers 
import tensorflow as tf 

base_model = VGG16(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), # Shape of our images
include_top = False, # Leave out the last fully connected layer
weights = 'imagenet')


for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
x = layers.Flatten()(base_model.output)

# Add a fully connected layer with 512 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

# Add a dropout rate of 0.5
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(base_model.input, x)

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001), loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['acc'])

history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data = validation_generator, steps_per_epoch = 100, epochs = 3)
```

I really want my model to more accurate as it is now.

Comment: please show some of the data generated by model.fit

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to ML & don't really know what you mean, Is it the stuff after the epochs are completed?

Comment: it is the data model.fit produces during training. Also try reducing yor dropout rate to .1 or .2. With .5 you are eliminating half the neurons during training.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want your model to be something like

```
preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input
input=Input((224,224,3))
x=preprocess_input(input)
x=base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16( include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3),
                                                                pooling='average', weights='imagenet')(x)
preds=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model=Model(inputs=input, outputs=preds)
model.summary()
```

the values you have for steps_per_epoch and validation steps  are typically set as number of samples//batch_size. Leave these values as None in model.fit and it will determine the right values internally. Also set verbose =1 soyou can see the results of training after each epoch.